# glGetUniformLocation returns -1 even though I used the variable in shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

It seems that the glsl compiler optimizes unused variable (remove).
In my case I used the variable but the `glGetUniformLocation` returns -1

```
rgbScene.addRenderStage(
    [&obj = std::as_const(model)](Camera* cam) {

    auto& mesh = std::get<Mesh>(obj);
    auto& program = std::get<ShaderProgram>(obj);

    glUseProgram(program);

    glBindVertexArray(mesh.getData<VAO>());
    int loc;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(
        loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "proj_matrix"),
        1, GL_FALSE,
        glm::value_ptr(cam->getProjectionMatrix())
    );

    glUniformMatrix4fv(
        loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "view_matrix"),
        1, GL_FALSE,
        glm::value_ptr(cam->getViewMatrix())
    );

    glUniformMatrix4fv(
        loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model_matrix"),
        1, GL_FALSE,
        glm::value_ptr(mesh.getModelMatrix())
    );

    glUniform3fv(
        loc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "light_direction"),
        1, glm::value_ptr(-(cam->getForward()))
    );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.getData<VertexData>());
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.getData<NormalData>());
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.getSize());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
});
```

I checked variable `loc` by debuging line by line in Visual Studio 2019 and at the last `glGetUniformLocation` returns -1

here's my vertex shader code

```
#version 460 core

uniform mat4 proj_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform vec3 light_direction;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;

out VS_OUT
{
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
} vs_out;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 P = view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);

    vs_out.N = mat3(view_matrix * model_matrix) * normal;
    vs_out.L = mat3(view_matrix) * (-light_direction);
    vs_out.V = -P.xyz;

    gl_Position = proj_matrix * P;
}
```

I tried changing the variable name, different order... but cannot fixed this problem

Is there any other rules for uniform variable in shader??

-- Edit --
for fragment shader,

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

in VS_OUT
{
    vec3 N;
    vec3 L;
    vec3 V;
} fs_in;

uniform vec3 diffuse_albedo = vec3(0.8, 0.3, 0.2);
uniform vec3 specular_albedo = vec3(0.7);
uniform float specular_power = 128.0;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 N = normalize(fs_in.N);
    vec3 L = normalize(fs_in.L);
    vec3 V = normalize(fs_in.V);

    vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);

    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(N, L), 0.0) * diffuse_albedo;
    vec3 specular = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), specular_power) * specular_albedo;

    color = vec4(diffuse + specular, 1.0);

    // color = vec4(1.0,1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Dose the fragment shader *"use"* the inputs `N`, `L` and `V`, too? Note, the active resources are determined when the program is linked. If an input to the fragment shader is unused, the uniforms which set the corresponding output variable in the vertex shader may not become active.

Comment: @Rabbid76  I added my fragment shader.

Comment: Is it possible the compiler simply elided the assignment to `loc`, as it is never used afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment shader inputs `N`, `L` and `V` variables have to be *"used"*, too.

Note, the active resources are determined when the program is linked. If an input to the fragment shader is unused, the uniforms which set the corresponding output variable in the vertex shader may not become active.

See [OpenGL 4.6 Core Profile Specification - 7.3.1 Program Interfaces](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=124&zoom=100,0,173), page 102:

> 7.3.1 Program Interfaces
>
> When a program object is made part of the current rendering state, its executable code may communicate with other GL pipeline stages or application code through a variety of interfaces. When a program is linked, the GL builds a list of active resources for each interface. Examples of active resources include variables, interface blocks, and subroutines used by shader code. **Resources referenced in shader code are considered active unless the compiler and linker can conclusively determine that they have no observable** effect on the results produced by the executable code of the program. For example, variables might be considered inactive if they are declared but not used in executable code, used only in a clause of an if statement that would never be executed, used only in functions that are never called, or used only in computations of temporary variables having no effect on any shader output. In cases where the compiler or linker cannot make a conclusive determination, any resource referenced by shader code will be considered active. The set of active resources for any interface is implementation-dependent because it depends on various analysis and optimizations performed by the compiler and linker
>
> If a program is linked successfully, the GL will generate lists of active resources based on the executable code produced by the link.

Comment: Thank you @Rabbid76 ...For test I added `color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` at the last of the fragment shader and it seems that the compiler optimized whole code of fragment shader except `color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` since the others are not used to compute the output of the fragment shader.

Comment: and `bool valid = glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR` returns true before `glUseProgram(program)` and right after `glUseProgram(program);`, `glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR` becomes false. Do you kown why it's an error? my `program` seems find. Is it because lambda or functor??

Comment: @신준섭 Sorry, but it's impossible to say, by seeing only this one (lambda) function. Note, [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml) returns different error types and there are different reasons why [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) may cause an error. Anyway I recommend to activate [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) to find OpenGL errors.

Comment: Thank you! a lot!!